# JQuery not showing elements according conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function sendState(state_id){
                var hd_read = $("#hd_read").val();
                var hd_toread = $("#hd_toread").val();
                var hd_reading = $("#hd_reading").val();

                var val = 0;
                var baseurl = "img/";

                switch(state_id)
                {
                    case 1:
                        if (hd_read == "0"){
                            document.getElementById('hd_read').value = "1";
                            document.getElementById('hd_toread').value = "0";
                            document.getElementById('hd_reading').value = "0";

                        }else{
                            document.getElementById('hd_read').value = "0";
                            document.getElementById('hd_toread').value = "0";
                            document.getElementById('hd_reading').value = "0";

                        }
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        if (hd_reading == "0"){
                            document.getElementById('hd_reading').value = "1";
                            document.getElementById('hd_read').value = "0";
                            document.getElementById('hd_toread').value = "0";

                        }else{
                            document.getElementById('hd_read').value = "0";
                            document.getElementById('hd_toread').value = "0";
                            document.getElementById('hd_reading').value = "0";

                        }
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        if (hd_toread == "0"){
                            document.getElementById('hd_toread').value = "1";
                            document.getElementById('hd_read').value = "0";
                            document.getElementById('hd_reading').value = "0";

                        }else{
                            document.getElementById('hd_read').value = "0";
                            document.getElementById('hd_toread').value = "0";
                            document.getElementById('hd_reading').value = "0";

                        }
                    break;
                }

                hd_read = $("#hd_read").val();
                hd_toread = $("#hd_toread").val();
                hd_reading = $("#hd_reading").val();

                var parameters = {
                    "book" : <?php echo $id_book; ?>,
                    "state" : state_id,
                    "val" : val
                };
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    data:  parameters,
                    url:   'change_state.php',
                    type:  'post',
                    dataType: "html",
                    beforeSend: function (){
                    },
                    success: function (response){
                        if (hd_read == "1"){
                            $("#img_read1").css("display","none");
                            $("#img_read2").css("display","inline-block");
                        }else{
                            $("#img_read1").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_read2").css("display","none");
                        }

                        if (hd_reading == "1"){
                            $("#img_reading1").css("display","none");
                            $("#img_reading2").css("display","inline-block");
                        }else{
                            $("#img_reading1").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_reading2").css("display","none");
                        }

                        if (hd_toread == "1"){
                            $("#img_toread1").css("display","none");
                            $("#img_toread2").css("display","inline-block");
                        }else{
                            $("#img_toread1").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_toread2").css("display","none");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

This function has to show or hide items according to which you pressed (0 for off, 1 for on)
I have no idea who may be failing in the code. I can not debug javascript function "success", but it is running because the states are changing.
When I start and none is pressed everything works fine, but when one is already pressed and I press another previous item status does not change to off.

Someone can help me?

Thanks.

Aggregate:

```
<a onclick="sendState(1);" id="img_read1" title="Read"><img src="<?php if($state == 1){ echo "img/read_sel.png"; }else { echo "img/read.png"; } ?>" /></a>
<a onclick="sendState(1);" style="display:none;" id="img_read2"><img src="<?php if($state == 1){ echo "img/read.png"; }else { echo "img/read_sel.png"; } ?>" /></a>
<input id="hd_read" type="text" value="<?php if($state == 1){ echo "1"; }else { echo "0"; } ?>" style="display:none;">

<a onclick="sendState(2);" id="img_reading1" title="Reading"><img src="<?php if($state == 2){ echo "img/reading_sel.png"; }else { echo "img/reading.png"; } ?>" /></a>
<a onclick="sendState(2);" style="display:none;" id="img_reading2"><img src="<?php if($state == 2){ echo "img/reading.png"; }else { echo "img/reading_sel.png"; } ?>" /></a>
<input id="hd_reading" type="text" value="<?php if($state == 2){ echo "1"; }else { echo "0"; } ?>" style="display:none;">

<a onclick="sendState(3);" id="img_toread1" title="To read"><img src="<?php if($state == 3){ echo "img/toread_sel.png"; }else { echo "img/toread.png"; } ?>" /></a>
<a onclick="sendState(3);" style="display:none;" id="img_toread2"><img src="<?php if($state == 3){ echo "img/toread.png"; }else { echo "img/toread_sel.png"; } ?>" /></a>
<input id="hd_toread" type="text" value="<?php if($state == 3){ echo "1"; }else { echo "0"; } ?>" style="display:none;">
```

the variable $state has come from a record in the database which is keeping well the value

Comment: Why can't you debug the success function? Add a breakpoint or some console.log statements

Comment: javascript just skip that part of the code by more that I put an interruption (I'm debugging with chrome console)

Comment: I don't get the mix up with native Javascript.

Comment: I know the code is ugly but I need to make it work as soon as possible

Comment: add an error function, maybe the 2nd time through your ajax is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your code shorter, and use just jQuery (as you planned at the beginning). Maybe it will just work:

**UPDATE:** Fully commented.

```
function sendState(state_id) {
    // If state_id = 1 and hd_read = 0, hd_read is now = 1, otherwise 0
    $("#hd_read").val(state_id == 1 && $("#hd_read").val() == 0 ? 1 : 0);    
    // If state_id = 2 and hd_reading = 0, hd_reading is now = 1, otherwise 0
    $("#hd_reading").val(state_id == 2 && $("#hd_reading").val() == 0 ? 1 : 0);
    // If state_id = 3 and hd_toread = 0, hd_toread is now = 1, otherwise 0
    $("#hd_toread").val(state_id == 3 && $("#hd_toread").val() == 0 ? 1 : 0);    

    // Never changes. Always = 0
    var val = 0;
    // Where is this variable being used?
    var baseurl = "img/";

    // Building up the parameters to send
    var parameters = {
        "book": <? php echo $id_book; ?> ,
            "state": state_id,
            "val": val
    };

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        data: parameters,
        url: 'change_state.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (response) {
            // If hd_read = 1 hide img_read1, otherwise show it
            $("#img_read1").css("display", $("#hd_read").val() == 1 ? "none" : "inline-block");
            // If hd_read = 0 hide img_read2, otherwise show it
            $("#img_read2").css("display", $("#hd_read").val() == 0 ? "none" : "inline-block");
            // If hd_readreading = 1 hide img_reading1, otherwise show it
            $("#img_reading1").css("display", $("#hd_reading").val() == 1 ? "none" : "inline-block");
            // If hd_readreading = 0 hide img_reading2, otherwise show it
            $("#img_reading2").css("display", $("#hd_reading").val() == 0 ? "none" : "inline-block");
            // If hd_toread = 1 hide img_toread1, otherwise show it
            $("#img_toread1").css("display", $("#hd_toread").val() == 1 ? "none" : "inline-block");
            // If hd_toread = 0 hide img_toread2, otherwise show it
            $("#img_toread2").css("display", $("#hd_toread").val() == 0 ? "none" : "inline-block");
        },
        error: function() {
            // Show any error on the console
            console.log('An error has occurred!');
        }
    });
}
```

For testing reasons, I needed to remove the PHP bits, but you can see it working basically:

http://jsfiddle.net/QVHhw/

What may be causing an issue is the PHP variable replacing the changes you're making via jQuery. You're manipulating the inputs values both on client and server side.

Comment: thanks, but there is something wrong with the logic and breaks all when I press some element, begin to disappear.
I tried to edit the code but I do not know what that means == 0? 1: 0

Comment: This is a ternary IF conditional. `condition ? true : false`.

Comment: And about the condition logic? When I press some element the others disappear and appear the other state of the same element. When I press one of them both dissapear...

Comment: I've fixed some conditionals on the block marked. Check the answer again.

Comment: Thanks for your time MelanciaUK. Still not working properly. When I press an element disappears another (does not show the other state)

Comment: I was just wondering here. The only change I've made was to make your code purely in jQuery, and shorter. But your question states that your own code wasn't working.

Comment: That was the problem, but that was not specifically. I I had conditions for the source of the image depending on the php variable.
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would at least help you in shortening the first part of your code. Replace beginning until switch with this:

```
var hd_read = $("#hd_read").val();
var hd_toread = $("#hd_toread").val();
var hd_reading = $("#hd_reading").val();

var val = 0;
var baseurl = "img/";

// Reset
$("#hd_read").val("0");
$("#hd_toread").val("0");
$("#hd_reading").val("0");

// Update
if (state_id == 1 && hd_read == "0")
    $('#hd_read').val("1");
else if (state_id == 2 && hd_reading == "0")
    $('hd_reading').val("1");
else if (state_id == 3 && hd_toread == "0")
    $('hd_toread').val("1");
```

It may not be the answer to your question, but easier read code may help you finding your error.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, and you're right, it is easier to understand the code in this way